# drawing and moving image above uiimageview - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to implement simple Image manipulation in Swift, I want to draw above the image of UIImageView.

So The interface will be as it is in the following picture:

[image: Descreption]

when clicking on the Emoji downside, i want to drag it and drop it on the imageview, or only clicking will move it to the uiimageview,

Then it can be moved around inside the uiimageview and save the whole image to galery.

I could not find useful source about this on google.

so Where to start with this?

Comment: Do you just want to drag and drop imageview over there(only position change). or do you want to merge 2 UIImage to generate single new image.

Comment: @MehulThakkar generating new image by dragging and dropping..

Answer (score 2):

If the emoji is a `UIImageView`, you can implement `touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)`. The following is where mainImageView is the view in which you want to add the emoji.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = event?.allTouches()?.first
    let touchLocation = touch?.locationInView(self.view)

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(emojiImageView?.frame, touchLocation)) {
        //your emoji imageView has been selected. 
        addImageviewToMainImageView(emojiImageView)
    } 
}

func addImageviewToMainImageview(imageView: UIImageView!) {
    imageView.removeFromSuperView()
    let origin = CGPoint(mainImageView.center.x , mainImageView.center.y)
    let frame = CGRect(origin.x, origin.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)
    imageView.frame = frame
    mainImageView.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

If you want to move the `emojiImageView` around within the `mainImageView`, you should subclass `UIView` to implement `touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)` and `touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)` in a similar fashion.

1) Detect the touch with `touchesBegan`, determine if one of the `mainImageView`s subviews has been touched. Set a reference to this subview.

2) If a subview has been touched, `touchesMoved` will use that reference to determine the new location of the subview:

```
let touch = event?.allTouches()?.first
let touchLocation = touch?.locationInView(self)
selectedSubview.center = touchLocation
```

Comment: I could get your point sorry. In the beginin ,as shown in the screenshot above, the emojiImageView, and mainImageView are in different Parent Views, however, they are in the same ViewController. so it looks like moving it from parent to parent ?

Comment: Does it need to be with no constraints as well?

Comment: I've written a gist for you to get started. Turns out you can't add a subview to a `UIImageView`. https://gist.github.com/BenJamminnn/30579e7921df8b1abb6d

Comment: that looks great, I will test the gist in my project. BTW, for me it does not matter wether i add to UIImageView or to UIView, i can change this part, and i dont think i would need an array of imageViews since i add only and only one emoji at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to combine 2 images, I am not adding code for drag and drop thing.

```
UIImage *mainImage = firstImage;
UIImage *smallImage = secondImage;
CGPoint renderingPoint = CGPointMake(50,50);
UIImage *outputImage = nil;

if (smallImage.size.width > mainImage.size.width || smallImage.size.height > mainImage.size.height)
{
    return smallImage;
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(firstImage.size);

[firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
[secondImage drawAtPoint:renderingPoint];
outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The outputImage here is output of 2 combined images. The renderingPoint is the Point at which you want to start drawing other image.

Just Add touches methods and get the point at which Touch ends, keeping that point as center point and by using smallImage's width, you can calculate its rendering point.

Also in keep in mind that here renderingPoint is with respect to original size of image, not the size of imageview, so make calculation accordingly to scale up or down to imageview.

Comment: since I started ios with Swift, i asked for swift code. As i understood from your code, what you are doing is screenshotting both images. not actually combining them(Resolution is way lower as u did). what i need is to drag and drop(maybe many times), then saving combined image to gallery.